# Storyboard in custom control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, custom-controls, storyboard

I have an usercontrol in silverlight that I'm trying to convert to custom control.
The usercontrol is working.
The customcontrol is working BUT has its storyboard not working.

the control is :

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControl);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsStartingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsStarting", typeof(bool), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsStartingChanged)));

    private static void OnIsStartingChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyControl control = obj as MyControl;
        if (control != null && control._layoutRoot != null && control._storyboard != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                control._layoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                control._storyboard.Begin();
            }
            else
            {
                control._layoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                control._storyboard.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private Canvas _layoutRoot;
    private Storyboard _storyboard;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _layoutRoot = GetTemplateChild("LayoutRoot") as Canvas;
        _storyboard = GetTemplateChild("IndicatorStoryboard") as Storyboard;
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    public bool IsStarting
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsStartingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsStartingProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

On debug, no error on control._storyboard.Begin();, but I can't see the animation ...

Does someone has an idea ? How to work with storyboard ?

Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT : Full source sample is available : http://vpclip.virtua-peanuts.net/WindowsPhoneApplication1.zip

Comment: Could you provide the full source?  Including your generic.xaml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set IsBusy to true in your button click handler you will see the animation does work. The problem is you are setting it to true before it has loaded so _layoutRoot and _storyboard are null and the animation never begins.

```
public class CustomBusyControl : Control
{
    public CustomBusyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomBusyControl);
        Loaded += (s,e) => ToggleBusy(this);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBusyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsBusy", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomBusyControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsBusyChanged)));

    private static void OnIsBusyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleBusy(obj as CustomBusyControl);
    }

    private static void ToggleBusy(CustomBusyControl control)
    {
        if (control != null && control._layoutRoot != null && control._storyboard != null)
        {
            if ((bool)control.IsBusy)
            {
                control._layoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                control._storyboard.Begin();
            }
            else
            {
                control._layoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                control._storyboard.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private Canvas _layoutRoot;
    private Storyboard _storyboard;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _layoutRoot = GetTemplateChild("LayoutRoot") as Canvas;
        Debug.Assert(_layoutRoot != null, "LayoutRoot is null");
        _storyboard = GetTemplateChild("IndicatorStoryboard") as Storyboard;
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsBusyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsBusyProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh yes, this was the issued ... thanks for your help. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head, but what happens if you move the "base.OnApplyTemplate();
" as the first line in the OnApplyTemplate() function?

```
   public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _layoutRoot = GetTemplateChild("LayoutRoot") as Canvas;
        _storyboard = GetTemplateChild("IndicatorStoryboard") as Storyboard;
    }
```

Does that help?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the same think.
Note that I'm using WP7, maybe does this matter ...

Comment: I don't *think* WP7 should affect it. I'm curious, I see that you are turning the _layoutRoot Visible first... is the storyboard inside the layoutRoot? Could be a timing issue if so - try leaving it visible initially and see if the storyboard fires that way to test it. Also, any reason you can't add making the layoutRoot visible as part of the storyboard? (Not part of the question of course, but just wondering).

Comment: I've tryed your suggestion and put visible to true, but nohihng better.

My project can be found here : http://vpclip.virtua-peanuts.net/WindowsPhoneApplication1.zip

maybe you can have an eye on it.

Thanks for your help